# How to call properties inside of a script runat at server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have a function that i need to call in the .aspx, and its in a  tag as follows, the problem i am having is that i need to evaluate a property in the .cs clas. How would I be able to accomplish this?.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Redirect() {
        location.href = "homePage.aspx";
    } 
 </script> 
     <script runat="server"> 
        protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (something is true from the propties set in .cs)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
               "ConfirmBox", "if(confirm('The numbers selected are not in the directory, you wish to continue?') == true){Redirect();};", true);
            } 
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing embedded code in aspx and in the cs file? If you would keep everything in the cs file it would be much easier.

Comment: not really i tried it... did not work. When i use the Page.ClientScript .... in my .cs, i need to put a return after it so it shows the pop up box, otherwise it just ignores it and continues

Comment: Sorry this is vb code as I have a vb project open right now, but it is the same in c#:
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "key", "if(confirm('The numbers selected are not in the directory, you wish to continue?') == true){Redirect();};", True)

Comment: please forget my comment, I am doing something wrong, it's not even working in my test project anymore :-(

Comment: it kind of works.. but its giving me that functiin Redirect() is undefined. (a javascript error)

Comment: I guess this is, because the included code is inserted before your Redirect function. You can also add your redirect function to the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Namespace: First put your class in a Namespace

```
namespace testNamespace
{
  public class test
    {
       public static bool tester(int x, int y)
        {
            if (x == y)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
    }
}
```

To import your Namespace use

```
    <%@ Import Namespace="testNamespace" %>

<script runat="server"> 
        protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (test.tester(2, 2))
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
               "ConfirmBox", "if(confirm('The numbers selected are not in the directory, you wish to continue?') == true){Redirect();};", true);
            } 
        }
    </script>
```

With this script you can pass values to your class file, validate it and return your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define  a property in your CS class and get access to it using Partial classes like this

CS:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public bool MyProperty { get; set; }

       protected void Page_PreInit(object sender,EventArgs e)
       {
           MyProperty = true;
       }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script runat="server"> 
    protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyProperty)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
           "ConfirmBox", "if(confirm('The numbers selected are not in the directory, you wish to continue?') == true){Redirect();};", true);
        } 
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button Text="text" runat="server" OnClick=Button1_Click />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```