# Disabling button from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I know this question has been asked before or similar questions asked but none of the solutions has yet fixed my problem.

I have a winform that has a button named `hitButton`. All I need to do is to disable this button from another class (i.e. not the form class).

My form class is:

```
public partial class BlackJackTable : Form
{
}
```

My separate class is:

```
class GameWon
{
}
```

I have tried exposing a public method in `BlackJackTable` like this:

```
public void DisableButtons()
{
    hitButton.Enabled = false;
}
```

and accessing from `GameWon` constructor (it doesn't seem to matter where in the class I access it from though) like this:

```
public BlackJackTable blackJackTable = new BlackJackTable();

public GameWon()
{
    blackJackTable.DisableButtons();
}
```

I have tried using a variable in `GameWon`:

```
public Button hit;
```

and assigning from blackJackTable:

```
GameWon gameWon = new GameWon();

public void Assign()
{
    gameWon.hit = this.hitButton; // or just = hitButton;
}
```

and disabling from `GameWon`:

```
hit.Enabled = false;
```

I have tried a couple of other things but none of them work. I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious as none of the methods I've tried have worked.

Any thoughts appreciated!

**Update**

I have managed to do the latter method with textboxes and pictureboxes, what's the difference with a button?

Comment: I can only imagine you aren't doing it for the right button. When you're calling DisableButtons and setting false to Enabled it should totally do the trick. It's all single threaded, right?

Comment: @YoryeNathan Yeah it's the right button and it's all single threaded. I just don't understand it.

Comment: Try setting Enabled to false at the ctor of the form that actually has the button. Just to test things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this using the latter method, but making the Button variable static.

```
public static Button hit;
```

It must have been getting class intances mixed up. Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it does not work is that you are calling `DisableButtons` on a wrong *instance* of `BlackJackTable`. Your `GameWon` class creates its own, invisible, `BlackJackTable` object, stores it in a `BlackJackTable blackJackTable` variable, and disables its buttons; the form object that is visible to you does not get modified.

To fix this, you should pass the instance of your `BlackJackTable` form to the constructor of `GameWon`, and set it to a variable:

```
private readonly BlackJackTable blackJackTable;

public GameWon(BlackJackTable blackJackTable) {
    this.blackJackTable = blackJackTable;
}
```

The code that creates an instance of `GameWon` class should pass the form as a parameter to the constructor:

```
GameWon gameWon = new GameWon(myBjTable);
```

Comment: @BaliC Please update the question with the change showing how you create `GameWon`, and what do you pass for its constructor's parameter. If you create it from a method of `BlackJackTable`, the call would look like `new GameWon(this);`

Answer (score 0):

You could return a value to the original class then disable the button:
Take a look at:
[How to call properties inside of a script runat at server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183307/how-to-call-properties-inside-of-a-script-runat-at-server/10183606#10183606)

Comment: Thanks, but its winforms, not asp.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of work in your constructors. This is often bad practice, particularly for forms. You seem to be modifying properties of objects on a form before the form is shown - I'm not surprised this produces unpredictable behaviour. If I were to guess, I'd imagine that the button state is being reset by form initialisation after your code has run. Forms are quite protective of their own lifecycle requirements, and I figure you must have run into an idiosyncrasy to do with how the form prepares itself for display.

I have to point out that you've presented quite a strange architecture here. I'm struggling to understand why you'd choose to arrange your application in this way. I think it would be preferable to communicate with the form and the game class from a controller class, possibly using events raised in the controller to allow the form to modify itself. Making a form modify its own state while it is visible on screen should always work.